# Plotly parallel plot gives wrong categorization after specifying color parameter

Tags: python, plotly

I have a dataframe with categorical columns and a target column with two categories - 0 and 1.

```
dfx.target.value_counts()
0    8062
1    3919
Name: target, dtype: int64
```

I tried to create parallel plot for them using plotly, This works fine, I am pasting my target column's output:

```
fig = px.parallel_categories(dfx)
fig.show()
```

[image]

Then I tried to color code them, so according to documentation, we can specify column's name.

```
fig = px.parallel_categories(dfx, color = 'target')
fig.show()
```

however, while specifying color scheme - which can be done using a column's name, I am getting wrong distribution in the target column : [image]

An additional category appears in gray color, also, the count of 0 and 1 in target column is wrong.

Note: There are no na in the data

Update: It turns out, it was version issue. After updating the package, I was able to do it.

Answer (score 1):

- have generated a sample dataset to plot
- following your code, specifying `color="target"` caused errors, invalid colors
- changed to use **pandas** series `map()` to build a series of **target** value to a color
- required addition of `dimensions` parameter so that **color** was not added as an additional category in trace.
- distributions are identical with or without using `color` parameter

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px

# build a dataframe for use in plot
V=6
a = [chr(i) for i in range(ord("A"), ord("A")+V)]
R=2000
dfx = pd.DataFrame({c:np.random.choice(a[0:V//(i+1)], R) for i, c in enumerate(["source","interim","target"])})

# the plot - use "target" for colors
px.parallel_categories(
    dfx,
    dimensions=dfx.columns,
    color=dfx["target"].map(
        {
            l: px.colors.qualitative.Light24[i % len(px.colors.qualitative.Light24)]
            for i, l in enumerate(dfx["target"].unique())
        }
    ),
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Rob , after hours of exploring, I have also implemented in the similar way. I have upvoted your answer, not accepted  as my issue was older version of the package. Also, do you know how we can style the categories? I can do it in go.parcats using labelfont, but I cannot find anything for px.parallel_categories. Thanks!

Comment: `px.parallel_categories().update_traces(labelfont={"size":26})` which is using graph objects on top of px contruction